# How to remove rebol script security level prompts

Tags: windows, rebol, rebol2

I'd like to remove the prompt when using `load/library`

1) From the Crimson Editor

- I tried to load the script using `-s secure allow` arguments with no effect

2) within the script `secure [ library allow ]`

- gives me another prompt "script requests permission to lower security level"

How can I manage Rebol security prompt free ?

I'd prefer a script level (more general) solution.

Comment: I use EditPlus and my command line settings is: rebol.exe --secure allow --script "$(FilePath)"

Comment: I remain to figure how to link a library within Rebol application prompt free.

Comment: Do you mean an encapped Rebol script? If so, put this in the header: encap: [secure none title "MyApp"]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried starting your script this way?

```
REBOL --secure none script.r
```

That should work.

See http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/secure.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to give -s as a start parameter to Rebol.

```
>> usage
```

The command line usage is:

```
REBOL <options> <script> <arguments>
```

All fields are optional. Supported options are:

```
--cgi (-c)       Check for CGI input
--do expr        Evaluate expression
--link url       Connect to Link
--help (-?)      Display this usage information
--nowindow (-w)  Do not open a window
--noinstall (-i) Do not install (Link, View)
--quiet (-q)     Don't print banners
--reinstall (+i) Force an install (Link, View)
--script file    Explicitly specify script
--secure level   Set security: allow ask throw quit
--trace (-t)     Enable trace mode
--uninstall (-u) Uninstall REBOL (Link, View)
--version tuple  Minimum version of script, when URL (View)
--noviewtop (-v) Do not start viewtop (view desktop)
```

Special command line options:

```
+q               Force not quiet (Link, View)
-s               No security
+s               Full security
-- args          Provide args without a script
```

Examples:

```
REBOL script.r
REBOL -s script.r
REBOL script.r 10:30 test@domain.dom
REBOL --do "verbose: true" script.r
REBOL -cswq
REBOL --cgi --secure throw --script cgi.r "debug: true"
REBOL --version 1.2.3 http://www.rebol.net/test.r ; view only
```

Although usage shows the same in R3, I guess security is not or not fully functional in Rebol3. Also some of the most recent versions of Rebol2 have a slightly different behavior regarding -i or --noinstall.